# PhP json_encode not working with array from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I did my first question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076287/php-cant-populate-array-from-selected-table-to-json-encode-and-receive-it-on-ja) abour populating an array to json_encode and pass it to my javascript on client side, but what I figured out is that the problem seems to be related to json_encode and the values that come from my table.
The table is filled with varchars, so it's a table with common categorys, like restaurant,shopping,etc.

I'm doing this loop to fill the array ( I had the while loop before but this one got me to understand the error)

```
$id=array();
for($i=0;$i<$nmr;$i++){
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
  $id[$i]=$row['Tipo'];
}
echo json_encode($id);
```

So, if I do it like this, my PhP page returns nothing. But if a print_r($id) it prints me the array with all the strings. If I echo $id[1]; it outputs one of the categorys, so I guess it's the json_encode no? I already set my DB to utf-8 because I noticed that json works that way, so what would be the prblem now?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Forgot to mention that if I do this:

```
  $id[0]="ola";
  $id[1]="ccc";
  $id[2]="sd";

  json_encode($id); 

 output: ["ola","ccc","sd"]
```

it gives me the array on the output. So it only happens when I try to encode the array filled with values from my DB.

**2nd Edit**

I said this above but I guess it's better if I show it.
The array is being populated because if I print_r($id) right after the json_encode($id) I get the populated array.

```
Array ( [0] => Restaurantes [1] => Cafés [2] => Shopping [3] => Eventos [4] => Hoteis [5] => Oficinas [6] => Combustiveis )
```

Comment: Please add current and desired output to your question

Comment: It is in the question, I want the array from json_encode() so I can get it on my javascript from client side (JqueryMobile app )

Comment: Is there anything in your error log?
Furthermore, if you try and echo something after json_encode($id); does that get outputted?

Comment: Yes, if I do, for example, echo $id[4]; after the echo json_encode[$id]; it outputs me one of the categorys

Comment: please show us what you get with a `var_dump` for `$id` right after your population loop, before you do the json_encode. Don't make us guess as the content of it when that runs successfully please =) (you don't show what `$nmr` is, for instance, so for all we know, that loop never adds data to $id, even if you in text-only say it does. Code/output or we can't believe you ;)

Comment: " But if a print_r($id) it prints me the array with all the strings. If I echo $id[1]; it outputs one of the categorys" there's the answer for the question.
$nmr is the number of rows and it's fine.

Comment: `json_encode` requires its input to be UTF-8 encoded. Likely yours isn't. See the duplicate for how to deal with UTF-8.

Comment: As I said "I already set my DB to utf-8 because I noticed that json works that way, "

Comment: The most common thing to overlook is to also set your **database connection encoding** to `utf8`. Again, see the duplicate.

Comment: deceze finally got it working. Before making this question I "did" the right thing to fix it as I set my DB to utf-8, but the values that were already on the table weren't utf-8. So I did that and now it's finally working ! Thank you :)